# Directive to validate input textbox to allow only numbers, a negative sign and a decimal value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to validate the input text box of type 'text' to allow only numbers or number with a negative or decimal value.
Example: 100, 002, -3.4, -6, 8.5
Currently the code is this which is not validating the '-' or '.'

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[myValidate]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }
  @Input('myValidate') highlightColor: string;
  @HostListener('keyup', ['$event']) onKeyDown(event) {
    let oldValue = event.target.value;
    let keyPressed = event.key;
    let keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (isNaN(oldValue.substr(oldValue.length - 1)) || keyCode === 32) {
      this.el.nativeElement.value = oldValue.substr(0, oldValue.length - 1);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for JavaScript's `parseFloat()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

```
parseFloat('123')
123
parseFloat('1.23')
1.23
parseFloat('-1.23')
-1.23
parseFloat('abc')
NaN
parseFloat('0002')
2
parseFloat('000123')
123
```

Comment: Hi christopher. Thanks for your reply. If i have '1000' entered in the textbox and i want to change it  to '2000'. So if i select '1' and delete it later on willing to enter' 2' to make the value as '2000'. Before doing this as '1' gets deleted the parseFloat() parses the remaining '000' in the textbox and returns me '0'. So i have to enter the entire '2000' again. Any suggestions regarding this

Comment: It's not best practice to replace user input with a 'valid' replacement. Instead, leave the user input as it is, and display an error message near the input box indicating invalid input